# Click on button to toggle display of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code that works perfectly to move elements from top, left, right or bottom sides, but seems to be, that it doesn't work with display property, here's my javascript code:

```
$('#icon-for-search').click(function () {
    var targetValue;

    if ($('#search-wrapper').css('top') == "0px") {
        targetValue = '55px';
    } else {
        targetValue = '0px';
    }

    $("#search-wrapper").animate({
        top: targetValue
        }, 500);
    });
```

I have a button with an id called "icon-for-search" and it toggles perfectly the top value of the #search-wrapper if it's clicked, but if I change it to display: block / none it doesn't work. Any particular reason? could someone explain me?

```
$('#icon-for-search').click(function () {
    var targetValue;

    if ($('#search-wrapper').css('display') == "none") {
        targetValue = 'block';
    } else {
        targetValue = 'none';
    }

    $("#search-wrapper").animate({
        display: targetValue
        }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: You can't animate `display`, a good way to get around this is animate opacity and then set the display property once the animation's complete.

Comment: display property cannot be animated. It has basically two states between block and none.

Comment: What kind of animating do you expect it to interpolate between "none" and "block"?

Comment: you're already using jQuery UI, just use jQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` properties.

Comment: thanks, then I'll have to toggle between classes and add different classes to each one? one with display block and one with display none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.animate works only with numeric CSS properties. You can just toggle element:

```js
$('#icon-for-search').click(function () {
    $('#search-wrapper').fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="icon-for-search">Search Icon</div>
<div id="search-wrapper">Search Wrapper</div>
```